# Как из [("123","321","222")] вывести все эти числа

Tags: python

есть список со скобкой внутри, как это отсортировать?
Как из [("123","321","222")] вывести все эти числа
print:
123
321
222
таким образом

Comment: Это называется не "скобка внутри", а кортеж

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем "в лоб", то так (это кортеж, просто перебираем элементы в нем):

```
print(a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2])
```

Можно чуть поинтереснее - уже не зависим от количества элементов (весь кортеж - нулевой элемент в списке, а дальше идем по элементам, добавляя пробел и не давая переводить строку):

```
for item in a[0]:
    print (item + ' ', end='')
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Answer (score 1):

>>> x = [("123", "321", "222")]

>>> " ".join(x[0])

'123 321 222'